# About 200 Errors When Using cmath in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, cmath

Trying to get code that was compilable in g++ to compile in VS2015. I looked around SO & Google with not much luck, yet cmath is documented in MSDN. I'm guessing I'm missing something really obvious or simple.

cmath is throwing a lot of errors most of the errors I'm getting during compilation, and half are in the form:

```
the global scope has no "<function>"
```

others are in the form

```
'<function>': redefinition; different exception specification

'<function>': identifier not found

'<function>': is not a member of "global namespace"
```

I don't understand why these errors are being thrown, but, if I use math.h, most of my compilation errors go away (including some in other standard libs that are crapping out, too).

Edit: As requested, the code. I'm using the sqrt & pow functions:

```
#include "vector.h"
#include <cmath>

using namespace vectormath;

vector::vector()
{
    this->_x = 0;
    this->_y = 0;
    this->_z = 0;
    this->_length = 0;
}
vector::vector(float x, float y, float z)
{
    this->_x = x;
    this->_y = y;
    this->_z = z;
    this->_length = sqrt(pow(_x, 2) + pow(_y, 2) + pow(_z, 2));
}

vector * vectormath::crossproduct(vector * a, vector * b)
{
    vector * result = new vector();

    result->_x = a->_y * b->_z - a->_z * b->_y;
    result->_y = a->_z * b->_x - a->_x * b->_z;
    result->_z = a->_x * b->_y - a->_y * b->_x;

    return result;
}

point::point()
{
    this->_x = 0.0;
    this->_y = 0.0;
    this->_z = 0.0;
}

point::point(float x, float y, float z)
{
    this->_x = x;
    this->_y = y;
    this->_z = z;
}

float vectormath::dotproduct(vector a, vector b)
{
    return a._x * b._x + a._y * b._y + a._z * b._z;
}

vector * vectormath::add(point * a, vector * b)
{
    vector * c = new vector();

    c->_x = a->_x + b->_x;
    c->_y = a->_y + b->_y;
    c->_z = a->_z + b->_z;

    return c;
}
```

Edit: and vector.h

```
namespace vectormath
{
    struct vector
    {
        float _x;
        float _y;
        float _z;
        float _length;

        vector();
        vector(float x, float y, float z);
    };

    struct point
    {
        float _x;
        float _y;
        float _z;

        point();
        point(float x, float y, float z);
    };
    vector * crossproduct(vector*, vector*);
    float dotproduct(vector a, vector b);
    vector * add(point * a, vector * b);
}
```

Comment: Where is your code that uses `cmath`? Do you have [mcve]?

Comment: Can you show your declaration of using cmath as well? Just in case :)

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error on http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net (VS compiler). I do not that the header has no include guard or `#pragma once`... could cause issues if it is included in several cpp files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between

```
#include <math.h>
```

and

```
#include <cmath>
```

is that the former puts things like `sqrt` and `pow` into the global namespace (i.e., you refer to them just by saying `sqrt` or `pow`) and the latter puts them into namespace `std` (i.e., you refer to them by saying `std::sqrt` or `std::pow`).

If you want not to have to prefix them with `std::` all the time, you can put individual ones in the global namespace explicitly:

```
using std::sqrt;
```

or (though this is not recommended) you can pull in the whole of `std` like this:

```
using namespace std;
```

The trouble with that is that there are a *lot* of names in `std` and you probably don't really want them all.